# Convert FASTA to GenBank

Tags: biopython, fasta, genbank

Is there a way to use BioPython to convert FASTA files to a Genbank format? There are many answers on how to convert from Genbank to FASTA, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 8):

before convert, you must asign alphabet to sequence (DNA or Protein)

```
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio.Alphabet import generic_dna, generic_protein

input_handle = open("test.fasta", "rU")
output_handle = open("test.gb", "w")

sequences = list(SeqIO.parse(input_handle, "fasta"))

#asign generic_dna or generic_protein
for seq in sequences:
  seq.seq.alphabet = generic_dna

count = SeqIO.write(sequences, output_handle, "genbank")

output_handle.close()
input_handle.close()
print "Coverted %i records" % count
```

for input:

```
>I28Q9A102FII8J rank=0668881 x=2144.0 y=1105.0 length=418
ACGTCATGAGAGTTTGATCATGGCTCAGGACGAACGCTGGCGGCGTGCTTAACACATGCAAGTCGAACGATGAA
GCTCCAGCTTGCTGGGGTGGATTAGTGGCGAACGGGTGAGTAACACGTGAGTAACCTGCCCTTGACTCTGGGAT
AAGCGTTGGAAACGACGTCTAATACCGGATATGACGACCGATGGCATCATCTGGTTGTGGAAAGAATTTTGGTC
AAGGATGGACTCGCGGCCTATCAGGTAGTTGGTGAGGTAATGGCTCACCAAGCCTACGACGGGTAGCCGGCCTG
AGAGGGTGACCGGCCACACTGGGACTGAGACACGGCCCAGACTCCTACGGGAGGCAGCAGTGGGGAATATTGCA
CAATGGGCGAAAGCCTGATGCAGCAACGCCGCGTGAGGGATGACGGCC
>I28Q9A102JMH72 rank=0320459 x=3829.0 y=3120.0 length=512
ACGTCATGAGAGTTTGATCCTGGCTCAGGATGAACGCTAGCGGCAGGCTTAACACATGCAAGTCGAGGGTAGAA
ATAGCTTGCTATTTTGAGACCGGCGCACGGGTGCGTAACGCGTATGCAATCTGCCTTTTACAGGGGAATAGCCC
AGAGAAATTTGGATTAATGCCCCATAGCGCTGCAGGGCGGCATCGCCGAGCAGCTAAAGTCACAACGGTAAAGA
TGAGCATGCGTCCCATTAGCTAGTTGGTAAGGTAACGGCTTACCAAGGCGATGATGGGTAGGGTCCTGAGAGGG
AGATCCCCCACACTGGTACTGAGACACGGACCAGACTCCTACGGGAGGCAGCAGTGAGGAATATTGGTCAATGG
GCGCAAGCCTGAACCAGCCATGCCGCGTGCAGGATGAAGGCCTTCGGGTTGTAAACTGCTTTTGACGGAACGAA
AAAGCT
```

you get:

```
LOCUS       I28Q9A102FII8J           418 bp    DNA              UNK 01-JAN-1980
DEFINITION  I28Q9A102FII8J rank=0668881 x=2144.0 y=1105.0 length=418
ACCESSION   I28Q9A102FII8J
VERSION     I28Q9A102FII8J
KEYWORDS    .
SOURCE      .
  ORGANISM  .
            .
FEATURES             Location/Qualifiers
ORIGIN
        1 acgtcatgag agtttgatca tggctcagga cgaacgctgg cggcgtgctt aacacatgca
       61 agtcgaacga tgaagctcca gcttgctggg gtggattagt ggcgaacggg tgagtaacac
      121 gtgagtaacc tgcccttgac tctgggataa gcgttggaaa cgacgtctaa taccggatat
      181 gacgaccgat ggcatcatct ggttgtggaa agaattttgg tcaaggatgg actcgcggcc
      241 tatcaggtag ttggtgaggt aatggctcac caagcctacg acgggtagcc ggcctgagag
      301 ggtgaccggc cacactggga ctgagacacg gcccagactc ctacgggagg cagcagtggg
      361 gaatattgca caatgggcga aagcctgatg cagcaacgcc gcgtgaggga tgacggcc
//
LOCUS       I28Q9A102JMH72           450 bp    DNA              UNK 01-JAN-1980
DEFINITION  I28Q9A102JMH72 rank=0320459 x=3829.0 y=3120.0 length=512
ACCESSION   I28Q9A102JMH72
VERSION     I28Q9A102JMH72
KEYWORDS    .
SOURCE      .
  ORGANISM  .
            .
FEATURES             Location/Qualifiers
ORIGIN
        1 acgtcatgag agtttgatcc tggctcagga tgaacgctag cggcaggctt aacacatgca
       61 agtcgagggt agaaatagct tgctattttg agaccggcgc acgggtgcgt aacgcgtatg
      121 caatctgcct tttacagggg aatagcccag agaaatttgg attaatgccc catagcgctg
      181 cagggcggca tcgccgagca gctaaagtca caacggtaaa gatgagcatg cgtcccatta
      241 gctagttggt aaggtaacgg cttaccaagg cgatgatggg tagggtcctg agagggagat
      301 cccccacact ggtactgaga cacggaccag actcctacgg gaggcagcag tgaggaatat
      361 tggtcaatgg gcgcaagcct gaaccagcca tgccgcgtgc aggatgaagg ccttcgggtt
      421 gtaaactgct tttgacggaa cgaaaaagct
//
```

Answer (score 2):

here's an update of Jose's answer for python3 and new biopython. Biopython doesn't use alphabets any longer.  Maybe it will save you a bit of time.

```
from Bio import SeqIO

input_handle = open("test.fasta", "r")
output_handle = open("test.gb", "w")

sequences = list(SeqIO.parse(input_handle, "fasta"))

# assign molecule type
for seq in sequences:
  seq.annotations['molecule_type'] = 'DNA'

count = SeqIO.write(sequences, output_handle, "genbank")

output_handle.close()
input_handle.close()
print("Converted {} records".format(count))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to convert the fasta to gb format for unsubmitted sequences, which dont have accession numbers. Yet to be submitted to NCBI.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).